# php file upload using IP Address

Tags: php

I just want to upload file to a server without using FTP the reason why is because authentication that make it slow and i though is it possible to upload file using IP address direct to the computer server. I hope there's someone who can help with this problem thank you in advance.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'png', 'gif', 'GIF', 'PDF', 'pdf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'doc', 'docx', 'ods', 'ODS'); // valid extensions

if($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']!=''){ //check if the is empty

    if($_FILES['img']['size']>10000000) //10 MB allowable maximum size of file
    {
        echo"This file is too large. File must be less than 10MB in size";
    }else{
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $Branch = $_SESSION['SBranchName'];
        $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
        $file = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];//tmp file the source file 

        //$path = '192.168.0.80/home/'.$Branch.'/'.$date.'/';
        //$path='\\\\192.168.0.80\\';
        $path = '192.168.0.80/upload/';
        chmod ($path , 0777);
        echo $path;

        $ext = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)){

            if(!is_dir($path))
            {
                mkdir($path, 0777 , true); // upload directory
                chmod($path, 0777);
            }   
            //$path = $path.strtolower($img);   
            $path = $path.$img; 
            if(file_exists($path)) //check file if already exist
            {
                echo"This file ".$img." exist!";
            }else{  
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
                {

                    //echo "<img src='$path' style='width:100px;heigth:300px;'/>";
                    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblbranch WHERE BranchName ='".$_SESSION['SBranchName']."' ")or die($mysqli->query);
                    while($row=$query->fetch_object()){
                        $BranchID =$row->BranchID;
                        $BranchName =$row->BranchName;
                    }
                    //$insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tblfileupload VALUES('$BranchID', '$BranchName', '$img', '$path', now(), '".$_SESSION['SUserName']."', now())")or die($mysqli->error);
                    $insert = $mysqli->query("CALL spfileuploadinsert(NULL,'$BranchID', '$BranchName', '$img', '$path', now(), '".$_SESSION['SUserName']."', now())")or die($mysqli->error);
                    echo"success";
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo"Invalid! the file must be jpg, pdf, xls, doc, ods";
        }    
    }//end of file size
}else{
    echo"No file choosen!";
}
?>
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` makes sure it's HTTP POST.

Comment: `$path = $path.$img;` should be `$path = $path.basename($img);`.

Comment: HTTP POST ? how does it works sir? the problem is the file is not tuploaded to server(192.168.0.80), but before sir its working via FTP but its slow due to authentication of FTP. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if you correctly understand what is going on.

Functions like `is_dir`, `mkdir` and `chmod` work with the file system of the server that the script is run on. That means, it will try to make folders named `192.168.0.80` on that server (e.g. your local system, if you run the script locally).

If your destination server on which you want to save the images onto only has ftp for file transfers to accept files, than you're stuck with ftp.

Otherwise if your destination server, *does* accept files, than you could use PHP's file upload functions for that.

EDIT: Check this comment by PHPGlue [php file upload using IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374600/php-file-upload-using-ip-address/49374693#comment85750481_49374600)

Comment: yes it create's 192.168.0.80 folder thats what happen to this script instead of create folder insider linux server that has 192.168.0.80 IP address, I cannot understand why is it not connect to the server(192.168.0.80) , thank you sir!